# Why does my Jquery slider does not display correctly?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I'm trying to implement the Slick Slider library in my WordPress custom theme to display a slider of images fetched from Advanced Custom Fields plugin. However, I'm encountering issues where the slider just stack the images on top of each other, the slider functionality is not working.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
    <article>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <h2 class="wp-block-heading has-text-align-center"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="hotel-description"><h2> Hotel Description: </h2> <?php echo $hotel_description; ?></div>
        <div class="hotel-services"><h2> Hotel Services </h2><?php echo $hotel_services; ?></div>

 <div class="hotel-images-slider">
    <?php
    // Output the images
    if ($hotel_image || $hotel_image2 || $hotel_image3) {
        echo '<div>';
        if ($hotel_image) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
        }
        if ($hotel_image2) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image2['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image2['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
        }
        if ($hotel_image3) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image3['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image3['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>


        

    <?php

endwhile;
?>
    </article>
```

Here's to code I added to functions.php of child theme

```
    function enqueue_slick_slider() {
    wp_enqueue_style('slick', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slick_slider');


function initialize_slick_slider() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.hotel-images-slider').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
            // Add more configuration options as needed
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'initialize_slick_slider');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your images inside a `<div>` itself, you currently only have *one* `<div>` with multiple images inside:

```
<div class="hotel-images-slider">
    <?php
    // Output the images
    if ($hotel_image || $hotel_image2 || $hotel_image3) {
        if ($hotel_image) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if ($hotel_image2) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image2['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image2['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if ($hotel_image3) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($hotel_image3['sizes']['medium']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($hotel_image3['alt']) . '" class="custom-image-class" />';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```